# Messaging Framework for .NET Compact Framework 3.5 that's compatible with Apache ActiveMQ?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, activemq-classic, messaging

I have a .NET CF C# client. I needed a simple messaging framework that is compatible with ActiveMQ on my server side. I understand that Apache.NMS and Apache.NMS.Stomp supports CF v2.0 but i believe there isn't much documentation to go with them. Can someone throw some light on the options that are available considering the fact that i want to use only ActiveMQ on the server side. (as one more messaging framework is an overkill?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache.NMS.Stomp works quite well on the CF and its your best bet other than writing your own mirco Stomp client for .NET CF.  There are tons of examples of its usage in the src bundle, just take a look at all the various unit tests there.  You can also direct specific questions to the ActiveMQ user group if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* (I haven't gone near the compact framework other than playing with it a long time ago) that the CF supports at least a base subset of WCF - if that is the case, there is a WCF NMS Provider available: http://activemq.apache.org/nms/apachenmswcf.html

(src available here: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/activemq/apache-nms/1.1.0/Apache.NMS.WCF-1.1.0-src.zip)

If all of the above is true, WCF is all you'd really need to deal with...